# How do you output in languages that are read from right to left?

Tags: c++, c, linux, windows

I'm curious how one handles output in languages (e.g. Arabic, Hebrew) that are read from right to left.  Almost everything in C/C++ or any language I have seen is premised on outputting from left to right.

Is there a system call or something that will force a terminal, for example, to print right to left?  Even so, inside a program strings are coded like string("this is a string").  Wouldn't it have to code something like string("string a is this") or some reverse function be used one everything?

Comment: Print it in usual way, read it from right to left

Comment: Unicode-aware terminals may use [Bidirectional hints](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr9/). Text is always stored in "reading order".

Comment: That's why std::string has an `rbegin()` method ;)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that in practice, a system that is configured for a right-to-left language will have terminal settings the print from right-to-left, so that the internals of a C/C++ program need not worry about it.

If that doesn't reassure you, here's a hack:

```
string str = "The look on your face is priceless.";
cout << "\u202e" << str << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

At the lowest layers, there are the [extended window styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for setting up a window in a "right to left" ordering: WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL, WS_EX_RIGHT, and WS_EX_RTLREADING.  Also, the API call, [SetProcessDefaultLayout with LAYOUT_RTL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633542%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  The right combination of these flags and APIs means the (0,0) coordinate is the top right of the window and the x-axis increases linearly.

Here's a link to the [classic MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688119.aspx) that explains all the fine details.