# WS_EX_RTLREADING, shell language, and SetThreadUILanguage

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++, localization

I have a ListView created by `CreateWindowExW()` with `WC_LISTVIEWW`. I then create columns using `LVCOLUMNW` and set the texts via `pszText`. Texts are in Arabic.

I would like the column texts of this list view to be displayed RTL, so I added `WS_EX_RTLREADING` to the extended style. However, it has no effect because [according to Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/extended-window-styles), the shell language needs to be Arabic or Hebrew.

I tried using `SetThreadUILanguage()` to set the thread language to Arabic, but it did not help.

What exactly is this "shell language"? Is it the language of the shell that's running my Win32 app? If yes, would that just be the language of `cmd.exe`, or the OS language? Is there a way to dynamically change this shell language at application runtime, and change it back?

Comment: This is likely overkill for what you're asking about, but this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20450355/11726740) mentions using the Windows API call [SetProcessDefaultLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setprocessdefaultlayout?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to change the default layout to be Right to Left.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Thank you. I was aware of the extended style of WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL, which would make the texts right-aligned. However I guess I was wondering about something different, something that would display "I eat apple" into "apple eat I".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, "shell language" is *not* the language of `cmd.exe`. I believe that this applies to the [Explorer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_shell). Here is another answer that agrees on that: *[is the Windows Explorer a shell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75122534/192373)*, and provides very good reasons for such interpretation.

The Microsoft [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/extended-window-styles) you linked explicitly says that `WS_EX_RTLREADING` has no effect when the shell language is not RTL. In addition to Hebrew and Arabic, this also includes Persian, Urdu, and other languages. Unfortunately, some of these language packs don't define the full Windows Explorer UI, and therefore don't count as "shell languages".

Please note that `WS_EX_RTLREADING` (or `LAYOUT_RTL`) may not be necessary for your use case; worse, it may cause undesired effects, like bitmap mirroring, as explained  [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/localizability/mirroring-in-win32#handling-direction-sensitive-graphics).

Texts in Arabic should be displayed perfectly even without LAYOUT flags. There may be some glitches when you deal with mixed text, where occasional English words appear inside an Arabic paragraph, but it may be hard to track and fix without help from somebody who knows the language well enough.

As for LISTVIEW, generic mirroring is not a very good idea. This control accepts `ILC_MIRROR` and `ILC_PERITEMMIRRORS` flags. See more in the [Microsoft Localization guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/localizability/mirroring-in-win32#mirroring-and-image-list-controls).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, very much appreciated. I wasn't really looking for mirroring, or LAYOUT RTL, which in my mind is different from WS_EX_RTLREADING? One shifts the positioning of entire text and the other changes the reading order of the text. Changing the reading order is what I was looking for. Regarding the shell language, the bottom line is there's no API that would allow us to change it at runtime of a win32 app(console or desktop), is that correct?

Comment: _the bottom line is there's no API that would allow us to change it at runtime of a win32 app_: correct.

Comment: Thank you. One more question, when adding LAYOUT RTL ex style to createwindowex, the columns added later would be RTL, but, when setting this ex style via SetWindowLongPtrA after listview has been created and columns added, the columns remain left to right. Is there a way to change the columns without re-creating them?

Comment: I would suggest not to rely on mirroring, but simply arrange (or rearrange) the columns [using ListView_SetColumnOrderArray](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-listview_setcolumnorderarray).

Comment: As for changing the reading order, the most common case could be to display strings like `1. first item` (after translation) as the user expects it (with `1` on the right). But for Arabic, you will probably use [Indic digits](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/bidiclass/AN), which are displayed as expected automatically.

Comment: Thank you so much for the tips. Re-ordering would work for RTL columns however the column names/titles for each column would still align to the left, no? Worst case scenario I'm thinking just re-creating them, but I will first try to see if I can find some API such as ListView_SetColumnOrderArray that may make the column titles right-aligned.

Comment: Alignment is a whole different story. You can have RTL text aligned to the left, or LTR (English) text aligned to the right. Personally, I prefer my column titles centered, but this could bring us very far form the original topic.

Comment: True that it would be off topic. My goal is to be able to align them to the right or left upon user interaction, but couldn't seem to find the way to do it. Maybe I should open another question?

Comment: Sure, go for it, but carefully describe your requirements. How will user interaction change alignment?

Comment: It could be as simple as a button click, the button is not part of the listview(obviously?) but could share the same parent window. Anyways, I'll dig a bit further if no luck I'll consider posting another question. Thank you so much for all your help and patience.